# Xcode SCM - not all files are being tracked. Use Versions?

Tags: svn, xcode, version-control

I am new to subversion.

I've tried Versions application, and very soon got disappointed - it doesn't copy .xcodeproj file properly(project doesn't launch and says that some file is missing) and is really bothering when I want to modify my project/remove some files. And I couldn't find any decent guide on it.

So I am trying out Xcode's built in SCM tool. It is working better, but it doesn't see when some files in the project were modified. I've got a folder called "CODE CORE" and it is placed in a directory that is one level up from my project directory. It has some code that I use among different applications. And when I change code within that folder, the edited file is not being marked with M symbol(in the SCM column). So it is not being committed to the repository, however the file itself is a part of working copy.

What may be the problem and how I fix it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm using Versions to manage my Xcode projects and haven't had any trouble at all... how exactly did you import your project into the repository?

Comment: In case it helps, I: 1. Create an Xcode project on the Desktop (making sure the "build" folder is removed). 2. Import the folder into the repository (making sure "Into a new folder created inside the selected item" is checked). 3. Checkout the appropriate folder to wherever I want it. 4. Tell Subversion to ignore the "build" folder (with the folder selected, choose Action > Ignore "build"). Then I start editing my project. When I've made a few changes, I just mark for addition/deletion any files that I've added or deleted, and commit the project folder.

Comment: Thank you Steve,
I copied the .xproj file from another project, edited it as I need, performed "add" SVN operation on it and committed to the repository.
What have I done wrong so far?

Comment: @Ilya: Did you copy the project folder or just the `.xcodeproj` file? The `.xcodeproj` file isn't the entire Xcode project—it's simply a project information file. When you work with Xcode projects, you usually need to work with the folder that contains the `.xcodeproj` file, because within this folder are all the code and XIB/NIB files.

Comment: @Ilya: When I work with Xcode projects, I always commit the project folder, not individual files. That way, all the files that have changed within the project folder are committed at once (of course, I still have to mark new files for addition and mark missing files as deleted).